# div without text with background-image

Tags: html, css

How to make a div with a background-image. I tried do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/9zygg1gt

```css
.mainFoto{
          width:100%;
          height:100%;
          background: url("http://www.vsttp.hekko24.pl/images/logo2.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
          
}
```

```html
<div class="row mainFoto">
</div>
```

It is a good way? How to display it?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty close! Just needed to set

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

to display properly. updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9zygg1gt/2/

When you set `height: 100%`, it needs to be relative to something else. Adding this little piece gives it something to be 100% high relative to.

Comment: http://patwoj.hekko24.pl/zespol/ it isn't work good. It should be cover foto. Do you know what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use your div height with % (try to use px instead). Width can use % but height will not work as you expect.

Comment: It should be responsive.

Comment: as @Never Say Never says, you should use 'px' . Further to make it responsive use media Queries.!

Answer (score 0):

I have used your code on `patwoj.hekko24.pl/zespol`
and added `height:inherit` to the div `mainFoto` [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Reagangallant/9zygg1gt/6/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `position:fixed`.

```css
  .mainFoto{
          width:100%;
          height:100%;
          background: url("http://www.vsttp.hekko24.pl/images/logo2.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
          position: fixed;
          
}
```

```html
  <div class="mainFoto">
    
  </div>
```